# 以下のようなPythonコードをwith文を使わずに実現することはできるでしょうか？

Tags: python

```
with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
  処理1
  処理2
```

Comment: [コンテキストマネージャー](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) が自動的に行うことを手動で行うのなら `with` 使わず実現できる(はずだ)けど, デメリットしかなさそうな？

Comment: [8.5. with 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) の効果/仕組み等が不要と言うのなら単純に順番にopenして終わりにcloseするとか、あるいは追加して例外処理が必要なら明示的にtry: except: finally:で囲むとか [8.7. クリーンアップ動作を定義する](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) すれば良いと思われます。同じ効果/仕組みが欲しいなら @oriri さんコメントのようにコンテキストマネージャーを使うことになるのでは？

Comment: 「実現することができるか」という質問ではなく, たぶん「[XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/)」だと思うので, 何が問題で何を知りたいのか, 質問を編集するのがよいかも

Comment: @kunif 「コンテキストマネージャーを使うことになる」とかいうコメントはしてませんが

Comment: @oriri さん、そうですか、その辺は誤読ですかね。ただ私が見つけて回答にした記事からすると、結局はそうなるように思えました。

Answer (score 1):

これらの記事とPEP 343,346に情報があるようです。
with文の仕様がどんなものか、どのような動きをするものかが説明されているのでしょう。

[Is Python *with* statement exactly equivalent to a try - (except) - finally block?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26096435/9014308)
[What is the equivalent try statement of the with statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59322585/9014308)
[PEP 343 – The "with" Statement](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/)
[PEP 346 – User Defined ("with") Statements](https://peps.python.org/pep-0346/)

こうした構文が：

> ```
> with EXPR as VAR:
>     BLOCK
> ```

こちらに展開されると書いてあります。

> ```
> mgr = (EXPR)
> exit = type(mgr).__exit__  # Not calling it yet
> value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
> exc = True
> try:
>     try:
>         VAR = value  # Only if "as VAR" is present
>         BLOCK
>     except:
>         # The exceptional case is handled here
>         exc = False
>         if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
>             raise
>         # The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
> finally:
>     # The normal and non-local-goto cases are handled here
>     if exc:
>         exit(mgr, None, None, None)
> ```

質問のように、`EXPR as VAR`の部分が2つ存在するのだとしたら、それぞれ用に`mgr,exit,value`のセットを作成して、`mgr1,exit1,value1`,`mgr2,exit2,value2`とでもしてみれば出来そうな感じです。
完全には等価に出来ないかもしれませんが、試してみてください。